# What is the C version of std::byte (for correctly handling IO)

Tags: c++, c, windows

What is the equivalent of the following C++ version `new std::byte[sizeof(data)]` in plain C?

I am trying to create a system byte buffer in plain C (for Windows 10) so that I can pass in a void pointer in order to communicate with a kernel driver via IOCTL.

The issue is the example I looked at is written in C++, and I am trying to figure out how to write it in plain C.

Here is an example of the C++ code I am trying to convert:

```cpp
std::byte* buffer;

try {
    buffer = new std::byte[sizeof(data)];
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    throw gcnew InteropException(e);
}

// Fill the buffer here

try {
    write(buffer); // Buffer is passed in as a void* aka PVOID
    delete[] buffer;
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    delete[] buffer;
    throw gcnew InteropException(e);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char[sizeof(data)]`

Comment: Or, if you wish, `uint8_t[sizeof(data)]`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Alright so if ``unsigned char buffer[sizeof(data)];`` should work what should I do about the delete[] buffer call?

Comment: @IgnoreExeption Nothing.  `delete` just needs the name of the object to delete.

Comment: @IgnoreExeption: Are you aware of `malloc`/`calloc` and `free`? That's what replaces `new` and `delete` in C (C++ differentiates `delete[]` from `delete` because it has to store extra metadata to handle destruction of arrays of classes, but C doesn't do any of that, so `free` works for everything).

Comment: "_Here is an example of the C++ code I am trying to convert:_": This is not C++, probably C++/CLI instead. Also, it is not going to be possible to line-by-line translate this code to C. It makes use of exceptions which C doesn't have. So you need to consider how to redesign the whole thing to work without exception control flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the equivalent of the following C++ version `new std::byte[sizeof(data)]` in plain C?

Use `malloc()`/`free()`, eg:

```
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(data));
if (buffer == NULL) {
    // handle error as needed...
    return;
}

// Fill the buffer here

write(buffer);
// error handling as needed...

free(buffer);
```

Comment: Oh thanks I don't know much about C++ so I did not know doing ``new`` was the same as malloc in plain C but that makes a lot of sense thank you!!

Comment: @IgnoreExeption `malloc()` simply allocates a block of memory, nothing more. `new`/`new[]` are more complex, as they not only allocate memory, but also construct objects within that memory. Likewise, `free()` simply frees memory, whereas `delete`/`delete[]` will destroy objects before freeing memory.  For trivial/POD types in both C and C++, like `char`s`/byte`s, you don't need to worry abut that detail, but for non-trivial types in C++, you certainly do.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte):

```c++
enum class byte : unsigned char {} ; // (since C++17)
```

Thus,

```c
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

or

```c
typedef enum byte : unsigned char {} byte;  // (since C23)
```

Comment: I wouldn't make my own enum. `std::byte` has custom wording that allows it to bypass strict aliasing, and your custom enum won't have that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good point! It's just another possible option.